# jboss server with jpa jndi perisitance problem

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss, eclipselink, jboss5.x

Greeting I am new to jpa as well as Jboss please provide me help.I know may this Q is duplicate but i search lot on Google but i didn't found anything 
my error:-

```
Error installing to Start: name=persistence.unit:unitName=#IportSapWSServerPU state=Create
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider from BaseClassLoader@62317221{VFSClassLoaderPolicy@14d4dc0d{name=vfsfile:/home/env128/Music/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/port_1/deploy/IportSapWSServer.war/ domain=ClassLoaderDomain@181b998c{name=vfsfile:/home/env128/Music/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/port_1/deploy/IportSapWSServer.war/ parentPolicy=AFTER_BUT_JAVA_BEFORE parent=ClassLoaderDomain@1a60604f{DefaultDomain}} roots=[MemoryContextHandler@568184345[path= context=vfsmemory://3j011-k4mwau-jlq6w2y8-1-jlq6wa5c-29 real=vfsmemory://3j011-k4mwau-jlq6w2y8-1-jlq6wa5c-29], FileHandler@1699669079[path=IportSapWSServer.war/WEB-INF/classes context=file:/home/env128/Music/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/port_1/deploy/ real=file:/home/env128/Music/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/port_1/deploy/IportSapWSServer.war/WEB-INF/classes/]]  delegates=null exported=[, conf.jpa, env.transaction.iportresponsedata, env.transaction.arinvoice, env.transaction.ardownpayment, conf.log, exceptions, env.transaction.iportrequestdata, META-INF, util, env.transaction.sapresponsedata, iport.outbound, iport.outbound.outboundDO, env.model, conf.quartz, iport.inbound, env.transaction.finalinvoiceprocess] <IMPORT-ALL>NON_EMPTY}}
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:448)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

jndi config:-
    
    
    
        
            IportDS
    
            oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
            jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.6.147:1500:orcl
            IPORTMAN_07072018
            IPORTMAN

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider` which would be covered in any java course (and you can't have searched very far if not encountering ClassNotFoundException). You don't have that class (part of EclipseLink) in the CLASSPATH. So put it in the CLASSPATH

Comment: I have related jars in my lib folder but u am having the same problem